# Dynamic PDF style problem in php?

Tags: php, html, css

when i create dynamic pdf (HTML to PDF) inline css not working like text padding or text margin.

Comment: (-1) Please add much more information. What library are you using to convert the document? What code are you using?

Comment: http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure that TCPDF is converting HTML to PDF.
We are generating a PDF using commands. We are drawing a PDF. Styles are not much effective there.

Try http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/examples.php#demo

Its easy and taking inline style

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

/* Type some style rules here */

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table><tr><td style='background-color:red'>asdasdasdasd</td></tr></table>


</body>
</html>
```